# Convert date to number format vba

Tags: vba, excel, date, format

I'm having issues copying a date from one file to another and preserving the format (dd/mm/yyyy) while using vba. 
A straight copy results in the dates that can be converted to US date format changing to mm/dd/yyyy and those that cannot (any date with dd > 12) changing to a string.
I have tried changing the date to a number first and then copy/paste (with the plan to go back to date format once the copy was complete) but this only changes format for the dates with dd<=12, the dates with dd>12 still come across as string format. Also the dates that successfully change to numbers seem to change to US format fist then to number format so I end up with the wrong date anyway
The strange thing is going through these steps manually (outside of vba) works fine, I can get all the dates into whatever format I want and the US format never appears.
Here is the code I have been using:

```
Sheets("Import").Select
PathName = Range("B2").Value
Filename = Range("B3").Value
TabName = Range("B4").Value
ControlFile = ActiveWorkbook.Name
Workbooks.Open Filename:=PathName & Filename
ActiveSheet.Name = TabName
Columns("A:A").Select
Selection.NumberFormat = "0"
Range("A2:A200").Copy Destination:=Workbooks(ControlFile).Sheets("Import").Range("A8:A206")
```

Any help or suggestions for things to try would be great.
Cam

Comment: I suspect that using the clipboard might be the problem.  Do you need to preserve formatting?

Comment: no I can deal with formatting once pasted but the process actually changes the value (ie. in spreadsheet 1 the date value is 42501 and after copy the date value is 42679...

Comment: Try `Workbooks(ControlFile).Sheets("Import").Range("A8:A206").Value = Range("A2:A200").Value`

Comment: Ok I just found something interesting, when I open the spreadsheet in vba the same dates are already in string format.

Comment: Without seeing the data, is it possible that you are copying formulas?  One way around this is to use `Range.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues`

Comment: If i open the spreadsheet outside of vba the dates are in date format

Comment: Maybe Columns("A:A").NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yy;@"

Comment: Hi Darrell, I tried that before but no luck.

Comment: Ricky! Legend! Can you explain why that worked??

Comment: Actually there are still strings where they used to be but I can work with that...

Comment: I hate to say it but all i did was record the macro.  Sometimes you over look the basics.  Glad to of helped.

Comment: There are several ways to fixing this issue but the simplest is  to just record the macro then alt it to make it work for your situation.

Comment: Ah actually I jumped the gun completely, the dates that are not strings are the incorrect date. I start with 11/05/16 (11th May in dd/mm/yy format) for example then using Ricky's suggestion I get 11/05/16 but it is in mm/dd/yy so that means it has changed to the 5th November....

Comment: Columns("A:A").NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yy;@"

Comment: Provided your source cells are in date format,read source `range.Value2` in an array and dump the array at destination.

Answer (score 1):

I would try one of these. I am confused to which format your wanting.

```
Workbooks.Open Filename:=PathName & Filename
ActiveSheet.Name = TabName
Range("A2:A200").Copy Destination:=Workbooks(ControlFile).Sheets("Import").Range("A8:A206")

'Workbooks(ControlFile).Sheets("Import").Columns("A:A").NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yy;@"
```

I am sure one of these will work

```
'Workbooks(ControlFile).Sheets("Import").Columns("A:A").NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yy;@"
```

If all else fails just run this after your code and make it any format your seeking.

```
Sub Change_Date()
Dim oCell As Range
Dim LastRow As Long

LastRow = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For Each oCell In ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A" & LastRow)
    oCell.Value = Format(Trim(oCell.Value), "dd/mm/yyyy")
Next oCell


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Living in Japan and having to deal with weird date conversions I have learnt the only real safe way to keep the formatting the way you want is to use `NumberFormatLocal` to set the cell the way you need it. No matter how you format the date in the VBA once it is in the cell, Excel seems to take over from what the local settings are set to.

The below code is what I would use in your situation to guarantee the format that you want.

```
   Sheets("Import").Select
   PathName = Range("B2").Value
   Filename = Range("B3").Value
   TabName = Range("B4").Value
   ControlFile = ActiveWorkbook.Name
   Workbooks.Open Filename:=PathName & Filename
   ActiveSheet.Name = TabName
   Columns("A:A").Select
   Selection.NumberFormat = "0"
   Range("A2:A200").Copy Destination:=Workbooks(ControlFile).Sheets("Import").Range("A8:A206")

   Workbooks(ControlFile).Sheets("Import").Range("A8:A206").NumberFormatLocal = "d/m/yyyy"
```

You could also use something like this on a date `1/12/2016`

```
Range("A8:A206").NumberFormatLocal = "dd/mmm/yyyy"
```

To give you an output of,

`12/Jan/2016` instead of `Jan/12/2016`